# Cual es la diferencia entre el contenedor std::map y std::unorderedmap

Tags: c++, c++11

Cuál es la diferencia entre estos los contenedores STL std::map y std::unorderedmap, además a la hora de buscar un elemento cual es más eficiente.

Answer (score 3):

Ambos con *contenedores asociativos*; asocian un valor, `T`, con una determinada *palabra clave*, `Key`. En otros lenguajes son llamados *diccionarios* o *mapas*.

#### `std::map< Key, T, Compare, Allocator >`

Los elementos son almacenados siguiendo un determinado orden: el determinado por el parámetro `Compare` de la plantilla. Se recorren en ese mismo orden.

Las operaciones de búsqueda, eliminación e inserción tienen complejidad *logarítmica* O(log n).

Es decir, el tiempo que tardan en realizar esas operaciones **depende de la cantidad de elementos en el**`map`. Cuantos mas elementos, mas lento.

#### `std::unordered_map< Key, T, Hash, KeyEqual, Allocator >`

Los elementos son almacenados sin un orden en particular, usando para ello una función *hash* o de firma ([wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funci%C3%B3n_hash)). Es **casi imposible** recorrerlos en ningún tipo de orden, siendo este aleatorio y dependiente de la función *hash* utilizada.

Las operaciones de búsqueda, inserción y eliminación tienen, *de media*, complejidad *constante* O(1).

Es decir, el tiempo que tardan en realizar las operaciones es independiente del número de elementos; tardan *aproximadamente* lo mismo exista 1, 10, o 10000 elementos.

Aquí, el estandar si indica que se implementan mediante *buckets* (perdón por el término, no encontré palabra adecuada en Español. [Wikipedia en inglés](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_(computing)) ).

Son esos *buckets* los responsables de esa *aproximación* en los tiempos.

#### Observaciones

- Ten presente que estas indicaciones **son requerimientos minimos**.
  Es decir, puedes encontrar implementaciones de `std::unordered_map`
  que sean **mas rápidas** de lo que indica el estandar, pudiendo
  llegar a ser igual de rápidas que `std::map`. No ocurre así con
  `std::map`. No es que el estardar lo impida, es que no es posible
  hacerlo más rapido de O(1).
- Ten presente también que se indica *complejidad* de la operación, **NO** tiempos. Puede ser, aunque improbable, que un `std::map` con **pocos elementos** sea más rápido que un `std::unordered_map`.
- Jugando con los argumentos adicionales, se puede *personalizar* el comportamiento. Por ejemplo, en el caso de `std::unordered_map`, **es posible** recorrerlos en un orden concreto, aunque es *complicado*. Para ello, se puede utilizar una función *hash* personalizada.

Answer (score 1):

Para no repetir lo comentado por trauma...

`std::map` implementa un árbol de nodos el cual se encuentra ordenado. La profundidad de las diferentes ramas tiende a ser la misma lo que obliga a recolocar nodos en muchas inserciones. Debido a esto este mapa proporciona unos tiempos de acceso muy buenos pero penaliza enormemente la inserción de nuevos valores. Esta recomendado para mapas muy estables con un gran número de consultas.

`std::unordered_map` utiliza el concepto de hash para agrupar las diferentes claves. Este mecanismo permite insertar elementos de una forma bastante rápida a cambio de penalizar sensiblemente las búsquedas. Mapas con vida corta o que reciben inserciones con asiduidad suelen tener mejor tiempo de respuesta con este tipo de mapa.